# Por que si quiero darle estilos a 3 divs en css, en la pagina me sale un 4to div, perdon por lo basico

Tags: div

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En realidad es bastante principiante pero no encuentro el motivo, en el archivo html practicamente en blanco creo 3 divs basicamente, en el css de selector div le agrego estilos y todo bien solo que me suma un div de mas, deberian ser 3 cuadrados con borde rojo en la pagina pero me salen 4, un dato interesante es que cada uno esta numerado, el cuarto solo tiene las propiedades pero obviamente nada adentro

```css
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: solid red;
    background: yellow;   
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link href="fonts.googleapis.com/…" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Buenas Mike. Por favor, proporciona tu código para poder identificar el problema.

Comment: Claro, gracias, seria este

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mynerve&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>


    
</body>
</html>

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir el código @Mike Soto De todas formas, no se ve que haya ningún error. Puedes añadir también el código css?

Comment: Si de echo estoy intentandolo, gracias T.T

Comment: Tu código no parece tener ningún problema.

Comment: Gracias, veré que pueda ser T.T

Comment: Imagino que es la caché del navegador. Cuando estás programando para web lo normal es desactivar la caché de tu navegador para que cada vez actualice todo, si no, te mostrará versiones antiguas de tu código y no estarás viendo los cambios en "tiempo real". Imagino que en algún momento tenías más divs en el html y eso es lo que estás viendo. Como dije, desactiva la caché de tu navegador para trabajar

Comment: @MikeSoto ve a tu archivo, dale al bóton derecho > inspeccionar y mira en la consola. Allí deberias ver todos los elementos en la página. Saludos

Comment: Hola Perdón por proporcionar una respuesta. Aun no tengo suficiente reputación para comentar. Primero de todo te recomiendo que apliques los estilos a clases y no directamente a los div, así puedes crear otros divs en un futuro con sus clases especificas y tener varios estilos de divs. Y por ultimo en tu código actual no se ve ningún problema que has comentado.
También puedes intentar limpiar el cache del navegador por si hay información de versiones pasadas que se han quedado en la memoria.
Ten mucho cuidado con cerrar todas las etiquetas.